# ehcache diskStore location and access

Tags: ehcache

I am using following configuration. I could like to see the cache file and see access the data from textpad/noteoad? is that possible? is there i can verify the data in Cache?

```
<cache name="cDBResponse" eternal="false"
        maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
         <cacheEventListenerFactory class="com.optumhealth.authorization.service.MyCacheEventListenerFactory"/>
         </cache>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should at least set diskPersistent="true" and check the location of the default diskstorage :
by default it's defined in this node
`<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>`
where java.io.tmpdir will depend on your OS